# Resize an image to specific ratio without enlarging it

Tags: image, math, resize

I need to generate new dimensions for an image to match a ratio of a given width and height ...but without increasing the size of the original.

The concept seems oh so simple yet I can't seem to join the dots.

Also, for code samples the language is PHP.

Update:

This is what I have so far:
http://codepad.org/fTdCNhQf

This is the output I need:

**[Example Image •](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIUEP.png)** *(can't embed yet)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since enlarging is not an option, your only options are cropping and extending.

Try this: let's say your image is `W*H`, and the desired aspect ratio of width to height is `R`.

- Using the width and the aspect ratio, calculate the target height `TH = W/R`
- Using the height and the aspect ratio, calculate the target width `TW = H*R`
- Calculate area changes `aH = ABS(TH-H)*W` and `aW = ABS(TW-W)*H`
- if `aH` is less than `aW`, use target width; pad or crop the image horizontally based on the sign of `TH-H`
- Otherwise, use target height; pad or crop the image vertically based on the sigh of `TW-W`

Here is a quick example:

```
Target R: 5/6
Image:  W=200, H= 300;
TH = 200/5*6 = 240
TW = 300*5/6 = 250
aH = 60*200=12000
aW = 50*300=15000
```

Resulting action: since `aH` is less than `aW`, crop image vertically to 240

Comment: Doesn't look to be working. (even if asb=abs). Ratio calc might be off?

Comment: @crolpa does your target `R` represent a width to height or a height to width? In the calculations I assume that `R` is width to height.

Comment: @crolpa I added an example, and fixed an error in the 4-th step.

Comment: @crolpa In your code you set `$new_width = abs($target_width-$width)`, which is not correct. New width should be `$target_width`; `$target_width-$width` is the amount of necessary correction (negative means "extend", positive means "crop").

Comment: Most of the time your formula works. With odd ratios like 12:1 it would produce an image larger than the original.

Comment: If images larger than the original images are not acceptable, then you need to choose crop all the time. Instead of picking the side that gets you a smaller absolute change of the area, always pick a side that results in the crop rather than an enlargement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification dasblinkenlight - she's all working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like ImageMagick libraries to generate an image or do you just need to generate the new dimensions based on a known ratio?  Also, do you need to discover the ratio from the existing image?

This may be useful then:
http://www.zedwood.com/article/119/php-resize-an-image-with-gd

Comment: Will be sizing an existing image (known width/height) to pre set dimensions (with PHP GD)